# "Similar questions" disappear on right click

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, similar-questions

I really like the "Similar questions" functionality when I'm composing a question.  However, there seems to be a bug when I want to right-click (e.g. to open the link in a new window).  On right-click, the "Similar questions" will re-load, and the question I was trying to load is now gone.

[See this in action here](https://youtu.be/NPJAav2mA3g)

It would be nice if the "Similar questions" were less dynamic, so that they don't change while I'm in the middle of interacting with them.

Comment: No repro in Chrome latest, Windows 10, but also this is a non issue. You can left click and you can middle click any link under "Similar questions", and they will open **in a new tab**. Why do you insist on right click??

Comment: I'm firefox on ubuntu

Comment: @ShadowWizardChasingStars I can't remember the exact link-opening default behavior of every widget on every website I go to.  I'm about to click a link - will it open in a new tab?  who knows?  I know, if I specifically ask for a new tab.